How do I download a dockerhub image as a zip/tar onto my downloads folder viewable via explorer?
I'm very new to this, and not 100% familiar with websites that only offer a "download" (in their terms, "pull") in the form of a command line that cannot perform a download through a browser (like github, that lets you download a repo, click on the green "code" button (only visible if Mobile Responsive design is desktop mode), it opens the "clone" box, and there is a "download zip", under "HTTPS").
I tried searching it up and all of them are either only through the CLI (command line interface), or some kind of posts saying their internet connection is slow or being blocked to connect.
So, how do I download a dockerhub "repository" as a zip (or any other archive file format) file that I can view it through explorer?
